# Source Deploy, does the package adhere to the package.xml api version?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

If I deploy with
Force:Source:Deploy command, and the version in the package.xml file is old (48), when the code or other metadata present in the package is at the later version (50).

- Will it only deploy the pieces of metadata that are valid up to and
  in the V48 api? or
- Will it fail the deployment and complain about the metadata elements that are extra and not expected?
- Conversely I assume if the version is more advanced and their is
  metadata missing for that specific API version then SF mAPI will again complain?

The challenge:
We are a large team of developers all joining our code in a single branch for a single package deployment (saves time), hence in a single folder, but each sub-team has its own package.xml file and these files are joined prior to deployment.
each sub-team could have operated on different versions of the API, So I am trying to understand the impact.
And so asking about the version on the Package.xml if it does not align with what is actually in the package.
And/or if different to the sfdx-project.json version.
What would be the outcome of this mis-alignment between package version and actual metadata being deployed?

Comment: Pretty sure it always uses the version listed in the sfdx-project.json, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, and so if the package does not meet that version then it should error, or just not deploy correctly, I assume it could be all of the above.
Thank you for what could be the actual answer.

I will add more context, to make this question more understandable.